# Фиксированное позиционирование flex блока

Tags: html, css

Подскажите пожалуйста, как используя flex, можно добиться результата, когда скажем, блок слева не скролится, тогда как блок справа прокручивается.

Для примера:
http://dev.wkornilow.org.ua/freshdesign/about.html

Видно, что при прокрутке левый блок также скролится

Answer (score 1):

Пусть у нас имеется следующая разметка:

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <ul class="nav">
        <li>Item1</li>
        <li>Item2</li>
        <li>Item3</li>
    </ul>
    <div class="main-content">
        <!-- контент -->
    </div>
</div>
```

На самом деле это не заслуга flex. Основная идея в том, чтобы вынести правую колонку из общего потока документа, т.е. задать ей свойство `position: absolute` или `position: fixed`, а также добавить свойство `overflow`. Делаем.

```css
/* сбрасываем стили */

html, body, .wrapper {
    height: 100%;
}
.wrapper {
    display: flex;
}
.nav {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
.main-content {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

Грубо говоря, свойство `overflow-y: auto` обрезает ту часть контента, которая выходит за область сверху или снизу от блока, добавляя при этом полосу прокрутки **только для этого** блока.